# How do we write some data when socket operation is going on

Tags: php, php-socket

I am new to sockets , and I am trying to display some data for the user to tell him to wait , while socket is fetching the data from the server , I used ob_flush , flush and some other functions also , but they didnt work, the text "Loading .... Please Wait" only appears after the socket is closed  , Here is my code

```
$fp = fsockopen("tcp:.......", port num, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) 
{
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Loading .... Please Wait";
    flush();
    fwrite($fp, $num . "\n");
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
    $cmd_res = fread($fp, 1000);
    echo $cmd_res;
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you have any solution , Please help me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the carriage return to the termination of the fwrite line:

```
fwrite($fp, $num . "\r\n");
```

Sockets will assume the new line with this combination.

Answer (score 0):

Few advices to make it work:

1. Make sure you have output buffering turned off in your php.ini:

   ```
   output_buffering = Off
   zlib.output_compression = Off
   ```
2. end any active output buffering buffer is active:

   ```
   while(ob_get_level()){ 
       ob_end_clean(); 
   }
   ```
3. disable any http server module that can buffer response (ie.: mod_gzip in apache)
4. mak sure browser is not buffering response (FireFox seems to output response directly while chrome waits for response to finish
5. Other browsers may require more data to be received before they can display it, make use of some spaces:

   ```
   echo str_repeat(" ",1024)."\n";
   ```